# How do I share readonly state between two or more reducers

Tags: javascript, redux

I need access to user editable state from two or more reducers. Is there a way to access state controlled by another reducer **without passing it** to the reducer through the action's payload? I want to avoid having every action send user settings to reducers.

**State**

```
{
  userSettings: {
    someSetting: 5
  },
  reducer1State: {
    someValue: 10 // computed with userSettings.someSetting
  },
  reducer2State: {
    someOtherValue: 20 // computed with userSettings.someSetting
  }
}
```

From the reducer1 I would like to get at `userSettings.someSetting` using something like the following:

```
function update(state={}, action) {
  if (action.type === constants.REDUCER_1.CALCULATE) {
    return _.assign({}, state, {
      someValue: 2 * GETSTATE().userSettings.someSetting
    });
  }
...
```

**I do not want** to have to send userSettings from the action like this:

```
export function calculate(userSettings) {
  return {
    type: constants.REDUCER_1.CALCULATE,
    userSettings: userSettings
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you make more state visible to one of the reducer instead of passing just a subset of the state?

Comment: Basically all reducers need userSettings so I'm looking for a way to pass it by default to all reducers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the golden rules of Redux is that you should try to avoid putting data into state if it can be calculated from other state, as it increases likelihood of getting data that is out-of-sync, e.g. the infamous unread-messages counter that tells you that you have unread messages when you really don't.

Instead of having that logic in your reducer, you can use [Reselect](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) to create memoized selectors that you use in your `connectStateToProps` function, to get your derived data, e.g. something along the line of this:

```
const getSomeSettings = state => state.userSettings.someSetting;
const getMultiplier = state => state.reducer1.multiplier;

const getSomeValue = createSelector([getSomeSettings, getMultiplier],
    (someSetting, multiplier) => {

});

const mapStateToProps(state) => {
    return {
        someValue: getSomeValue(state)
    }
}

const MyConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: I still don't understand how this solves the problem of having to pass someValue through the action to get it to the reducer.  How does the reducer use `getSomeValue` without first having access to the shared `state`?

Comment: The point is that you don't store data in the shared state if that data is something that you can calculate from other, existing state. So in the above example, `getSomeValue` doesn't store anything in the shared state, it gets the data it need from the shared state (`someSetting` and `multiplier`) and calculates `someValue` based on `someSetting` and `multiplier`.

Comment: @Hummlas I tried hard to find a scenario where using userSettings was not creating derived data and could not. Reselect has worked perfectly for my use cases so far. Thanks!

Comment: But you still have to pass `someSetting` to *both reducers* in order to be able to call `getSomeValue`, which seems impossible when using `combineReducers`...

Comment: What @Hummlas is saying is that instead trying to share state at the reducer level (or root reducer level in this case), you move that logic up to the component level. So, in your component you combine the two states you want to combine and pass that to your container.